# Is `label` ignored in forest packing stage?

Tags: forest

I installed forest `2016/03/04 v2.0.2`. With the following code,

```
\documentclass[convert={size=640}]{standalone}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{forest}
% parsing tree
\forestset{
  parsing tree/.style={
    for tree={
      math content,
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
    where level=0{
      for children={no edge},
      phantom
    }{
      draw,
      label=right:{ok},
      delay={
        content=\circ
      },
      if n children=1{calign=child edge}{}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  parsing tree
  [
  [
  [] []]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I end up with

[image]

Is label ignored in packing? Can I make it respected in packing stage?

Comment: Yes, it is. And sorry, no. (At least not for now. I'm aware that this could be useful, but there are severe technical problems that would have to be overcome.)

Comment: This is why [my code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302713/) didn't use `label` ;). @SašoŽivanović

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use the dynamic tree version?

Comment: @cfr Dynamic tree version doesn't reflect the semantic structure in the code. Label is semantically more appropriate.

Comment: Note that the current version of Forest only supports one label anyway. But why don't you pick something semantically appropriate if that's important? Or make it so that you specify the labels as the node content e.g. `[something left:something right, blue ...]` or whatever. You could repurpose `label` if you are sure you don't need it, although I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: @cfr You can circumvent the restriction of one label for a node with `node options={label=left:left,label=right:right}`. But, label is still ignored in packing.

Comment: Oh. I wouldn't call that 'semantic'. It is very appearance focused, in fact. But there you go. You can also avoid it by using the redefinition I posted recently.

Comment: @cfr I think `wff` and `cyswyllt` could have been written with `label`s intead of nodes without edges if labels were not ignored in packing stage. If labels were calculated in packing stage, the implementation could be simpler and a bit more semantic with `label`s.

Comment: There are significant disadvantages to using `label`s - not just that they are ignored during packing. Whether it would be simpler in this case or not, I'm not sure. But it would certainly be less flexible. It is the same with using `tikz`. You lose flexibility in terms of what Forest provides. (Which is why `prooftrees` is more flexible than `justtrees`. I refused to give in and use `tikz`. `label` would have the same trouble. `justtrees` is unsatisfactory as a result, in my view.)

Comment: Why not call `wff` and `cyswyllt` `right label` and `left label` or something like that if you want appearance-based markup? That's less semantic, in LaTeX's sense, as far as I can tell. But it makes no odds: if you prefer that and find it more intuitive, use it. I can't really see why that's not an acceptable solution. Note that the new version of Forest *does* allow multiple `label` options to accumulate.

Comment: @cfr `right label` and `left label` look as good as `wff` and `cyswllt`. I have no problem with using `wff` and `cyswllt`. I was not sure about implementing what looked like labels with nodes without edges because I'm still just learning forest and TikZ and it was hard to wrap my mind around conceptually two different things(label and nodes without edges).

Comment: A `label` just is a `node` as far as TikZ is concerned. The difference is whether the labels are created as nodes within the tree structure (which means they are packed and can be manipulated in all the Forest ways, as well as the TikZ ways) or whether they are created as nodes independent of the tree structure using the `tikz` key (in which case they are not created until the tree has been packed, constructed and drawn).

Comment: That is, TikZ uses `append after command` to add a node for the `label` text, applying the `every label` style and any other options as appropriate.